# libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: basic_string Error?

Tags: c++

Here is a function I'm writing that receives a string of words separated by spaces and adds each word to an array. I keep getting an error that says "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: basic_string." I can't seem to find what the error is.

```
void lineParser(string line, string words[])
{
    string word = "";
    int array_index = 0;
    int number_of_words = 1;
    int string_index = 0;
    while (string_index < line.length())
    {
        if (line.substr(string_index,1) != " ")
        {
            int j = string_index;
            while (line.substr(j,1) != " ")
            {
                word += line.substr(j,1);
                j++;
            }
            words[array_index] = word;
            array_index++;
            word = "";
            number_of_words++;
            string_index = j;
        }
        else
        {
            string_index++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should pass a reference to a resizable container like std::vector to your function instead of an array pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable `j` is allowed to increase without bounds checking also.  It will eventually excede the length of the string you're using it as an index into (`.line.substr(j,1)`).

A very bad answer would be to add a space at the end of your string `line` before searching for `' '` characters.  A much better answer is to check j against the length of the string before calling any function which accesses the characters in the string using it as an index.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm new to this website. I've set your answer as correct now.

Answer (score 1):

You've got no array bounds checking when accessing `words`.  If the array passed in doesn't have enough space allocated, you'll run past the end of the array.

As you've pointed out below, that isn't necessarily the problem, but it's impossible to say without seeing the rest of your code (main, for example).  It's also really bad code, you should never just assume that you know the length of an array, ever.  You're using C++, make use of STL containers.  It will save you untold headaches associated with arrays.

Comment: So isn't that issue covered with this execution in main?

        const int SIZE = 5;
 string values[SIZE];
 cout << lineParser("1234 total TEST 5535 AEA", values);